# Waterfall animation export glitch

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I'm working on a waterfall animation for a game dev project, the engine we are using does not allow for animating of textures so I decided to create a seamless water texture and create a sort of 2D animation effect by growing and shrinking the planes with offset UVs to make it appear like it is animating. (I am animating the scale from zero to 1 back to zero over 3 frames)

*In blender this works*

Unfortunately, whenever I try to export the model to bring it into the game environment it is appearing as if the animation is flashing (It seems the scaling animation is taking place over more than 3 frames - I estimate somewhere around 6/9 frames).

I unfortunately do not have a way to do this animation differently, I thought about moving the geometry instead of the texture and using a looped path animation but this did not give the same visual effect I was looking for.

Any help achieving this effect is appreciated! Please find some images and the blender file with the waterfall so you can see how I set up the animations below!

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]